# update fields in a records which is coming as a string

Tags: apex, map, list, string, insert

I am getting fields and its values in form of a string, for example:
`field1*Value1,Field2*Value2,Field3*Value3`

I need to update above 3 fields in a record with their given values.

```
Object ob=new object();
ob.field1 = Value1;
ob.field2 = Value2;
ob.field3 = Value3;
update ob;
```

Could you please let me know, what should be the approach for the above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a separator for field & value ? Without a proper separator we can only split by comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming * is the separator between the fields and values :

First, we need to split the string by comma for fetching list of all field value pairs like below :

```
String apiStr = 'field1*Value1,Field2*Value2,Field3*Value3';
List<String> fields = apiStr.split(',');
```

Second , we need to define the sObject type for populating the fields:

```
// Replace Account with the sObject required
Schema.SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
SObject newAccount = accountType.newSObject();
```

Third , we need to loop over the result in step 1 and split it again by *. Then populate it in the sObject instance created in step 2 :

```
for (String fieldValue: fields) {
    List<String> fieldValueLst = fieldValue.split('*');// Replace * with the separator between field and value
    newAccount.put(fieldValueLst[0].trim(), fieldValueLst[1]);
}
```

Complete code will be like below :

```
String apiStr = 'field1*Value1,Field2*Value2,Field3*Value3';
    List<String> fields = apiStr.split(',');
    
// Replace Account with the sObject required
    Schema.SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
    SObject newAccount = accountType.newSObject();
    
    for (String fieldValue: fields) {
        // Replace * with the separator between field and value
        List<String> fieldValueLst = fieldValue.split('*');
        newAccount.put(fieldValueLst[0].trim(), fieldValueLst[1]);
    }
```

**Note**: Depending on the field types , above code will require additional handling.

References:

- [sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)
- [sObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm)

Comment: Very well said.

Comment: Thank you so much, This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try [String.split()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split):

> Returns a list that contains each substring of the String that is terminated by either the regular expression regExp or the end of the String.

Comment: by doing String.split(): I am able to make an array of 
Field1*Value1

Field2*Value2

Field3*Value3
Now how to update these fields with these values'